# want to add image in Bundle-items in magento 2 in option_info

Tags: magento2

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYtmF.png)
As Shown in image there is a Select dropdown I have to add Upload Image option

I am using Product form modifer-class
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/admin/custom-product-creation-form/modifier-class/

```
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="bundle_selection_image" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string"
                >Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\SelectionImage</item
                >
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">500</item>
            </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```